# heroku -cli is not installed properly?

Tags: node.js, heroku-cli

Hi Everyone I'm beginner in Nodejs.I have created small project.I have to push into heroku for that I have downloaded heroku cli for windows 10.I have installed. After Installation It shows completed.I have pinned this app in taskbar .If I click to open the software.It's asking again to install.But In control panel It shows installed.Can anyOne give me a solution? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Once you install `heroku-cli`, you no longer need the installer application. Since it is a CLI, or Command Line Interface, it can only be used through a Command Prompt. There is no GUI, or Graphical User Interface, like most Windows 10 applications.

Open Command Prompt by right-clicking the Start Menu, choose Run, enter `cmd` and click OK. Now type `heroku` and press enter. If you receive a help message, `heroku-cli` was installed successfully. Now follow the instructions in the Heroku tutorial, such as running `heroku login`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but No use.I have followed your instruction.It is connecting to the internet

Comment: @demodevelopers Do you mean Cortana is searching the web? Try this instead: right-click the start menu and choose Run. Enter `cmd` and press enter.